# Get custom events data in application insights into array using c#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights

I have to get most number of cities browsing my application. I am getting that data using App insights. However I want to store that data into an array and pass it to a test function using SELENIUM c#.I am using below query in analytics. I installed app insights nuget package and connected to it.

```
customevents
 | where timestamp >= ago(24h)
 | summarize count() by client_City
 | order by count_ desc
```

**C# code:**

```
TelemetryClient telemetry = new TelemetryClient();
 telemetry.InstrumentationKey = "xxxx";
            telemetry.TrackEvent("eventname");
```

I want to store the data that is coming from analytics query to an array in c#. Is there a way we can do it.

Answer (score 2):

With the `TelemetryClient` you can only write data, not query data.

You have these options:

1. Export the data to Blob Storage or Sql Server for example and create a query in there that you can read using .Net (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-export-telemetry#export-samples)
2. Export the data from the query in your question to a CSV file and read that in .Net (This is a manual action)
3. Use the Application Insights REST Api to query the data directly in .Net. See https://dev.applicationinsights.io/quickstart/.

I think option 3 is best fit for you.